# Maven Surefire does not give correct test counts when executing Spock tests in parallel

Tags: maven, groovy, parallel-processing, spock, maven-surefire-plugin

My project contains a series of Groovy integration test scripts for a few APIs.  Previously, these tests executed concurrently and took up to 3 hours to execute.  I was able to reduce this time to just 5 minutes by using Spock's [parallel execution feature](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0-M4/parallel_execution.html#parallel-execution).

The new problem is that the Maven Surefire reports no longer give the correct test counts for each test suite.  The total test count is correct (more or less), but Surefire is mixing up which tests go in which report.

Here is my pom:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.dsg.payments</groupId>
    <artifactId>e2e</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>This will be used to execute normal credit card End2End test cases</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <build-helper-maven-plugin.version>3.1.0</build-helper-maven-plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M3</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <gmavenplus-plugin.version>1.11.0</gmavenplus-plugin.version>
        <swagger-annotations-version>1.6.0</swagger-annotations-version>
        <groovy.version>3.0.7</groovy.version>
        <spock.version>2.0-M4-groovy-3.0</spock.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-annotations-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>0.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/groovy</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/test/groovy</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/groovy</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Groovy compiler -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gmavenplus-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Java compiler -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Unit Tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is an example of a test class

```
package com.dsg.payments.e2e.creditcard

import com.dsg.payments.paygate.ApiClient
import com.dsg.payments.paygate.api.AuthorizationApi
import com.dsg.payments.paygate.model.PaygateAuthorizationRequest
import com.dsg.payments.paygate.model.PaygateAuthorizationResponse
import com.dsg.payments.paygate.model.PaygateEncryptedCardTenderResult
import org.junit.Test
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Title
import spock.lang.Unroll
import util.Constants
import util.CreditCardType
import util.EntityFactory

@Title("CreditCard-Authorization")
class Authorization extends Specification {

    // Constants
    @Shared
    private static final applicationName = Constants.APPLICATION_NAME
    @Shared
    private static final referer = Constants.REFERER
    @Shared
    private static final basePath = Constants.BASE_PATH

    @Shared
    private AuthorizationApi authorizationApi

    def setupSpec() {
        // Setup ApiClient to make requests to stage AN01
        ApiClient authApiClient = new ApiClient()
        authApiClient.setBasePath(basePath)
        authorizationApi = new AuthorizationApi(authApiClient)
    }

    @Test
    @Unroll
    def "Auth request with valid #cardType card returns authorized response"(CreditCardType cardType) {
        when:
        PaygateAuthorizationResponse authorizationResponse = authorizationApi.authorize(applicationName, EntityFactory.getPaygateAuthorizationRequest(cardType), referer)
        PaygateEncryptedCardTenderResult tenderResult = authorizationResponse.getTenderResults().getEncryptedCardTenderResults().get(0)

        then:
        // No exception thrown by authorization api client means successful 201 response
        authorizationResponse != null

        where:
        cardType << [
                CreditCardType.VISA_Credit_1,
                CreditCardType.VISA_Debit,
                CreditCardType.VISA_Commercial_Debit,
                CreditCardType.VISA_Commercial_Credit,
                CreditCardType.VISA_Purchasing_Credit,
                CreditCardType.VISA_3DS_Not_Enrolled,
                CreditCardType.DISCOVER,
                CreditCardType.AMERICANEXPRESS_1,
                CreditCardType.MASTERCARD_Debit,
                CreditCardType.MASTERCARD_Credit,
                CreditCardType.MASTERCARD_Premium_Credit,
                CreditCardType.DINERS,
                CreditCardType.JAPANCREDITBUREAU
        ]
    }

    @Test
    @Unroll
    def "Auth request with valid cvv for #cardType returns cvv response M"(CreditCardType cardType) {
        when:
        PaygateAuthorizationResponse authorizationResponse = authorizationApi.authorize(applicationName, EntityFactory.getPaygateAuthorizationRequest(cardType), referer)
        PaygateEncryptedCardTenderResult tenderResult = authorizationResponse.getTenderResults().getEncryptedCardTenderResults().get(0)

        then:
        // No exception thrown by authorization api client means successful 201 response
        authorizationResponse != null
        tenderResult.getCvvResponse() == "M" // Raw CVV result code for "match"

        where:
        cardType << [
                CreditCardType.VISA_Credit_2,
                CreditCardType.VISA_Debit,
                CreditCardType.VISA_Commercial_Debit,
                CreditCardType.VISA_Commercial_Credit,
                CreditCardType.VISA_Purchasing_Credit,
                CreditCardType.VISA_3DS_Not_Enrolled,
                CreditCardType.DISCOVER,
                CreditCardType.AMERICANEXPRESS_2,
                CreditCardType.MASTERCARD_Debit,
                CreditCardType.MASTERCARD_Credit,
                CreditCardType.MASTERCARD_Premium_Credit,
                CreditCardType.DINERS,
                CreditCardType.JAPANCREDITBUREAU
        ]
    }
// ...
}
```

There are 3 more test classes (Capture, Refund, and Cancel) with a similar structure that use the @Unroll annotation to re-run the same test with different credit card numbers.

Interestingly, when using Spock parallel execution, Surefire adds an extra test to the report for each test method - one for each credit card and an additional test for the method itself.  This is not a huge problem in itself, but it is less than ideal.  The real problem is that the Surefire report mixes the classes together (for example, Capture tests end up in the Refund, Cancel, or Authorization reports).  This makes it hard to tell from the report which tests failed.

I'll also include my SpockConfig.groovy, which configures the parallel execution:

```
runner {
    filterStackTrace false
    optimizeRunOrder true
    parallel {
        enabled true
        dynamic(4.0)
    }
}
```

It has taken much trial and error to get the pom in a state where the tests are all executing correctly in parallel fashion.  This is the only combination of dependencies, plugins, and versions that works so far.  The only thing that is wrong are the Surefire reports.  Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: 3 hours to 5 minutes is a nice reduction. Btw you don't need the `@Unroll` annotation in Spock 2.0 as it is enabled by default, and you have never needed `org.junit.Test`. As @user944849 suggested I'd try using surefire-3.0.0-M5 as they have some critical fixes.

Comment: I just saw the surefire issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1643 `JUnit 5 in parallel execution mode confuses Surefire reports` which is still open and slated for the yet unreleased 3.0.0-M6

Comment: Slightly OT question: 3 hours to 5 minutes sounds spectacular for only switching on the parallel option without any other type of optimisation. More exactly, it is a 36:1 ratio. I have never used parallel execution before, but `dynamic(4.0)` seems to imply 4 threads per processor, i.e. your machine should have 36/4=9 processors, probably rather 8 and the execution time speedup is closer to 32:1 in reality. Is that about right? If so, is it 8 cores or 4 cores + hyper-threading? I am intrigued, hence the question.

Comment: The error reports are getting mixed up in my tests too. I am running Spock tests parallely and i have more than one test, each with data driven using where. Is there any fix yet for this ?

Answer (score 0):

First: I notice the surefire version in the POM shown is `3.0.0-M3`. The [mvnrepository.com maven-surefire-plugin list](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin) shows the latest is `3.0.0-M5` and a lot of the changes in the newer versions appear to be report related.

Second: check the Maven output log to see if the `maven-surefire-report-plugin` is being used. If it's there, ensure it is using the same version of Surefire as was used to run the tests. You can do that by adding this to the POM:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

You may not be using Failsafe for integration tests yet, but it's a good idea to keep the Surefire family of plugins using the same version. So when I need to adjust Surefire version, I set them all in the hope of saving someone future troubleshooting pain.

Comment: The latest released version is currently 3.0.0-M5

Comment: Exactly. @user944849, please note what is written on top of that page: _"This is the **road map** of the development"_

Comment: Fixed, thank you. Point remains that OP is not using the most current available version and several of the fixes in the 2 more recent milestones appear to be reporting-related.